# Specific format of Day and Date Via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How to format Day and Date in below mentioned format:

> Wednesday, Feburary 8, 2017

I am using below mentioned code but it reflects format  as `"Wed Feb 08 2017 20:19:40"`

```
var d = new Date();
```

Comment: please try searching before asking...the web is full of resources about formatting dates in javascript

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5mLj6qud/

Comment: Other duplicates: [*Q: Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?s=1|6.6980) and [*Q: How to format a JavaScript date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?s=2|5.7777).

Comment: Oh, where options for *toLocaleString* are supported, you can use: `new Date().toLocaleString('en-us',{weekday:'long',day:'numeric',month:'long',year:'numeric'})`.